# Vue.js - show details of nested array inside another array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want to show my relationship values inside my result array. my results looks like this.

```
 "counciler": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "family",
            "description": "test description here",
            "created_at": "2020-04-16T07:57:31.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-04-16T07:57:31.000000Z",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "stack change",
                    "email": "stack123@test.com",
                    "phone": "000000000",
                    "profile_image": null,
                    "address": null,
                    "user_type": "counciler",
                    "email_verified_at": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-04-16T13:32:51.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-04-16T13:32:51.000000Z",
                    "deleted_at": null,
                    "pivot": {
                        "category_id": 1,
                        "user_id": 8
                    }
                }                
            ]
        }
    ]
```

my question is i want to get my users array details into a `v-for` for list all my users in that category. how can i achieve this one?

i also tried this one but not working

```
<div v-for="user in counciler.users" :key="user.id"></div>
```

Comment: `counciler` is an array, so you will have to `v-for` over it before looping over the users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should iterate over the `counciler` array and then loop through the users items :

```
<template v-for="counc in counciler"
    <div v-for="user in counc.users" :key="user.id"></div>

</template>
```

Comment: You're welcome, the `<template>` that i used is not the root element

Answer (score 2):

You try to access the object `counciler.users` but this doesn't exist because counciler is an array, not an object. Either you need to loop over `counciler` then other the users. Or just select the first object like so: `counciler[0].users`